# How to know the path to an R file inside it when it is sourced?

Tags: r, bash

When I source a file in R, I want to know inside it what its path is. Is there a way to do so in R?

```
source("somefile.R")
```

See `BASH_SOURCE` (I just need `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` though) for a similar feature in bash.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

EDIT: The following solution does not work as expected. See `f()` being called outside `main1.R`.

```
$ cat main1.R 

f = function() {
if (!is.null(src <- Sys.getenv("R_SOURCE")) && nzchar(src)) {
    cat("my name is '", src, "'\n", sep = "")
}
}

f() 
$ Rscript main.R 
R> source2 <- function(path, ...) {
+   path <- normalizePath(path)
+   oldsrc <- Sys.getenv("R_SOURCE")
+   on.exit({ Sys.setenv(R_SOURCE = oldsrc) }, add = TRUE)
+   Sys.setenv(R_SOURCE = path)
+   source(path, ...)
+ }
R> 
R> source2('main1.R')
my name is '/private/tmp/y/main1.R'
R> f()
R>
```

In `bash`, no matter where the function is called, it always knows where it is defined.

```
$ cat ./main1.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

function f {
  declare -p BASH_SOURCE
}
$ cat ./main.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

source main1.sh
set -v
declare -p BASH_SOURCE
f

$ ./main.sh 
declare -p BASH_SOURCE
declare -a BASH_SOURCE=([0]="./main.sh")
f
declare -a BASH_SOURCE=([0]="main1.sh" [1]="./main.sh")
```

EDIT:

The following solution based on `getSrcFilename()` does not work when one wants to access the path within the file run by `Rscript`.

```
$ cat f.R 
f=function() {
  getSrcFilename(f)
}

(function() {
  print(getSrcFilename(f))
})()
$ Rscript f.R
R> f=function() {
+   getSrcFilename(f)
+ }
R> 
R> (function() {
+   print(getSrcFilename(f))
+ })()
character(0)
R>
```

Comment: Please don't just mention these so-called related things. It is better to provide some real working implementation.

Comment: Sure, whatever you want. I think adding context often helps, whether the asker or a prospective answerer. But it's your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the solution given doesn't work, then presumably you don't just want to know the path when you source the file, but permanently for any objects it creates.

The `srcref` system provides at least some of what you want, if `options(keep.source=TRUE)`

Eg:

```
> source("~/Downloads/main.R")
> getSrcFilename(svy_vglm,full.names=TRUE)
[1] "svgam.R"
> getSrcFilename(f)
[1] "main.R"
> getSrcDirectory(f)
[1] "/Users/tlum005/Downloads"
```

The directory is the directory by which the file was looked up: if you just did `source("main.R")`, the directory would be `.` rather than its absolute form.

Rewriting your `main.R` you might get

```
f = function() {

   cat(getSrcDirectory(f))

}

f()
```

Two weaknesses here are that srcref attributes are copied by assignment and `f()` relies on knowing its own name. If you did

```
g<-f
g()
rm(f)
g()
```

you might want the two calls to `g()` to both return errors (since `g()` wasn't sourced) or both to return the directory, but you wouldn't want one of each. This can be worked around in this case with `sys.function()`: if `main.R` is

```
f = function() {

   cat(getSrcDirectory(sys.function()))

}

f()
```

the assignment works

```
> source("~/Downloads/main.R")
/Users/tlum005/Downloads
> f()
/Users/tlum005/Downloads
> g<-f
> g()
/Users/tlum005/Downloads
> rm(f)
> g()
/Users/tlum005/Downloads
```

I wouldn't advocate *using* this method -- I can't think of a situation where you wouldn't be better off just putting the source code somewhere better organised -- but I think it does answer the question.

Comment: I will need to be able to access the filepath in the file as well (the post has been updated) besides just in a function. It also seems to be wasteful to keep a file path attribute for every function in the file when only reference to the file path string should be sufficient. So it is very hard to come up something really similar to Bash's BASH_SOURCE.

Comment: "I can't think of a situation where you wouldn't be better off just putting the source code somewhere better organised.": I think the R community do need to appreciate that the simple design in Bash can actually do a lot of things. The main problem of R package system is that the dependency are usually too heavy. In order to use a small function in a package, I have to load a whole package which can be very time-consuming. If something equivalent to BASH_SOURCE is available in R, then I can source files more precisely so that the slow package loading problems can be avoided.

Comment: Any update to your solution? As I have shown, it is not equivalent to BASH_SOURCE.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `path_abs()` from the fs package?

https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/path_math.html

Comment: What do you propose the argument to `path_abs` should be? That function needs to start with some (arbitrary) path string.

Comment: Good point @r2evans, I was thinking
`
file_to_source <- ""somefile.R"
path_abs(file_to_source)
source(file_to_source)
`

Comment: If `path` includes a path in it, then `path_abs()` keeps it; if the path is relative, then `path_abs` uses the current working directory. Neither of these will work when the current working directory and the directory of the script being called are different, ala `source("/path/to/file.R")`.

Comment: This is not relevant. Uses must not explicit mention its path with the script.