# How to getSrcFilename() of an unnamed function?

Tags: r

I want to get the R file path in the unnamed function below. But I am not sure how to do it. Would you please let me know whether there is a way to do it?

```
$ cat main.R
options(keep.source=T)

f=function() {
    getSrcFilename(f)
}

print(f())

print((function() {
    getSrcFilename(...) # I want to get the R file path. I am not sure what to write here.
})())
```

```
R> source('main.R')
[1] "main.R"
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There may be better ways to solve the problem. Function closures aren't aware of their own source meta data. You need a named reference to extract that information from it's name.

Comment: @MrFlick, you might be informed by the remaining conversation on the OP's other recent question, it provides context: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61196587